# nested Rowkey in Hbase tables

Tags: hadoop, hbase

i have a weather data base with 4 tables : province,city,station, instantHarvestinfo,dailyHarvestInfo
and the relation between tables is parent-child:
(province,city): R(1,m)
(city,station):R(1,m)
(statin,istantharvestInfo):R(1,m)
(station,dailyHarvestInfo):R(1,m)
 i want put all of them in one bigtable in hbase and for echa one create a column family..but i dont know how define my row key...i think i need a nested row key that in each step get a split of my rowkey that related a comuln family and give me information of same cf..but how i cant define it?
please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there.

I guess you are going to save huge amount of `istantharvestInfo` and `dailyHarvestInfo` for each station.

Since there is parent-child relationship in your data model, I think you could

design the schema as:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
**Row-Key**:              Province + city + station + timestamp 
--------+---------------------+------------------------------------------
Family  | Qualifier           |          Value
--------+---------------------+------------------------------------------
        | istantharvestInfo   |        "value of istantInfo"
   F    +---------------------+------------------------------------------ 
        | dailyHarvestInfo    |        "value of dailyInfo"
--------+---------------------+------------------------------------------
```

Note that there is only one Family, because we should always make #family as small as possible.